# ReactJS: Javascript not targetting div element in react but targets div element in html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a piece of javascript in the body section of index.html that modifies a div element with id='aww-wrapper'.

If I create a div element in the body of the index.html file above the script like so, once the webpage gets loaded, the script modifies the div element as intended.

```
<div style="width: 600px; height: 400px;" id="aww-wrapper"></div>
  
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var aww = new AwwBoard('#aww-wrapper', {
  });
</script>
```

I need to do the same thing using react, however, if I make a react div element with the same ID in the App.js file instead of in the html file, the script no longer modifies/acts on the react div element.

```
import './App.css';

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{width:'600px', height:'400px'}} id="aww-wrapper">
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The code is meant to create a whiteboard app using the following awwapp.com code. I dont know whats wrong with the react implementation, is the script tag running first before the react div is made?

If you'd like to try this yourself, place this in the head section of index.html and use the html code above to create the whiteboard.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://awwapp.com/static/widget/js/aww3.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Inside your App component, include a useEffect, and in the useEffect, `cinst aww = new AwwBoard('#aww-wrapper', {
  });`; The useEffect behaves as a componentDidMount when you pass an empty list of dependencies and it will be triggered after your component has mounted(The div with the ID will be present)

Comment: Hi @Harsha, thank you for your response, I have tried adding that code like so inside the function App() section:


`useEffect(() => {
    const aww = new AwwBoard('#aww-wrapper', {
        });
  }, [])`

But it is now giving me an error 'failed to compile' - 'AwwBoard is not defined', the js code works when its inside a script tag in html but react fails to compile it when i put it inside useeffect. Is there a way around this?

Comment: try logging window.AwwBoard in your console and check what it prints

Comment: Thanks for your response @HarshaVenkatram, it links me to a file loaded into the webpage from awwapp.com called Index.js, the AwwBoard variable is defined by this code `var AwwBoard = window.AwwBoard = function AwwBoard(el, opts) {...` is there a way I can link the code in react to this external index.js file so it recognises the AwwBoard object?

Answer (score 0):

You cant mix React with an external script like that, because React handles the rendering.
The aww script cant find the element because React hasnt renderd it yet. So it would need to run after the render. But, if you do happen to get the element, React might just re-render it on some state change, which will cause your whiteboard to disappear again.
Unless they provide an npm package, which I cant seem to find, you cant load it the way youre trying to.

Comment: Hi Emre thanks for the clarification that makes sense, is there any way I would be able to implement the webapp on react or would it only work in HTML? Some people have suggested I use useEffect() to hold the aww script but when I run it, react doesnt compile it saying 'AwwBoard is not defined'

Comment: So with React youd need an npm package, so you can use `import AwwBoard from 'awwboard'` for example, which is what you would then use in the `useEffect()`. But since its not a package, you cant import it.
What might work is `window.AwwBoard`, but not sure